# How to know the offset value of type structure property?

Tags: c#, c, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to know that how I can get the offset value of structure in C language 
and I am converting the structure into c#. eg. If offset value of log_level_offset will be 0 then similar way what would be the offset value for next and rest of the property.

Example of my structure:

```
typedef struct TestStruct
{
    const AVClass *av_class;
    int log_level_offset;
    enum AVMediaType codec_type;
    const struct AVCodec  *codec;
    void *priv_data;
    int bit_rate_tolerance;
    uint8_t *extradata;
    int extradata_size;
    float b_quant_factor;
    uint16_t *intra_matrix;
    uint64_t channel_layout;
} TestStruct;
```

Comment: This would make a good exam question.

Comment: While this question is probably *motivated* by the rewrite to C#, the question is 100% about how C lays out the structure and would probably benefit from being rewritten to not mention C# at all. If you need to know how to lay out a similar structure in C# afterwards then this is likely a new question. I'm not saying that you *must* remove all traces of C# from the question but I daresay you would get better answers if you tagged it with C than with C#.

Comment: [C11 provides the `offsetof()` macro](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3) to return the offset in bytes from the beginning of the `struct` for any of a `struct`'s members.

Comment: Also please note that the elements' sizes (and with this their offsets) heavily depend on the platform the Code is compiled for. Also padding may occur  (see "*C structure padding*" here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15 and here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p17).

Comment: alk : The IEEE links you provided just stole the C Language documents written by K&R back in the early 1970's.  The bibliography even says : ''The C Reference Manual'' by Dennis M. Ritchie, a version of which was published in The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, Prentice-Hall, Inc., (1978). Copyright owned by AT&T.

Comment: @jdweng: The document I linked is a copy of the ***C11 Standard**'s draft*. C11 is the *current* C Standard. Please see the doc's "Abstract" and its [Forword](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Foreword).

Comment: It looks a lot like the original : http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/docs/chistory.html

Comment: @jdweng: "*It looks a lot like the original*" I never doubted this :-) The reason for this similarities might be that the standardisation guys are taking care a lot to not change the language to harsh, to not break any of those millions and millions and ... of productive C code being around.

Comment: The IEEE never writes their own specifications.  The basically take vendor submitted standards and give them an IEEE number and approves the standards.  Rarely do they change the vendors specification.  Only spec I know of that was written by IEEE is the HL7 standard of transfer of medical records where the IEEE was paid by medical industry to write standard.

Comment: "*log_level_offset will be 0*" As `log_level_offset` is not the 1st member its offset most likely isn't 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know the byte position of a struct member in [c](/questions/tagged/c), use the `offsetof` macro from stddef.h:

```
#include <stddef.h>

printf("%zu", offsetof(struct TestStruct, log_level_offset));
```

(`%zu` since the macro returns an integer of type `size_t`.)

Note that this takes potential padding bytes in account, so the offset on one system is not necessarily the same as on another system.

Comment: Actually we are using c structures in c# and there we haven't implemented it as we are using as a external reference. So how can we get offset in c# without creating structure?

Answer (score -3):

Pointer as 4 bytes in c# and usually defined as IntPtr.  Integers and floats are 4 bytes. uint8 is 8 bytes.  See structure below

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct TestStruct
        {
            IntPtr av_class;
            int log_level_offset;
            int codec_type;       //may be different depending on size of c language code
            IntPtr  codec;
            IntPtr priv_data;
            int bit_rate_tolerance;
            IntPtr extradata;
            int extradata_size;
            float b_quant_factor;
            IntPtr intra_matrix;
            ulong channel_layout;
        }
```

Comment: "*uint8 is 8 bytes*" bits not bytes (in C).

Comment: Also beware of C's structure padding.

Comment: alk : It is not padding, it is alignment. Padding would add bytes to the structure and the size would change.  Alignment starts objects on addresses of multiples of 2, 4, 8, 16. The alignment only becomes an issue if you have an array of structures.

Comment: True, alignment issues might lead to padding, padding *between* the single member elements of a `struct`, to provide proper alignment of the latter. And no, (in C, as per the Standard) there shall *never* occur padding *between* an *array*'s elements.

Comment: The alignment is added by the linker not the compiler.  So you do not want double set of padding so that is why you do not add padding between array elements.  You leave it up to to the linker.  There can be pseudo ops in the assembly code so the linker can properly perform the alignment.

Comment: 1) Array elements are not padded in C, not by the compiler, nor by the linker. 2) The C compiler decides if structures are padded (for what ever reasons it might feel this would be necessary). No way around it. The linker would not be able to do this any more. In C the size of a `struct` and with this the sizes and offsets of *all its member elements* essentially need to be known at compile time, way before the linker gets involved. This is necessary for example to create correct code for all this pointer stuff C code is using quiet heavily.

Comment: The compiler generates the code that accesses the struct, so at that point alignment must be taken care of, or the compiler wouldn't be able to generate any code. The linker has nothing to do with it.